# Rails 3.2 - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Can't find a newly created object in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Does somebody faced this weird behavior with ActiveRecord? I'm working under Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3..

I have the following method:

```
def send_response (number, text, t_id=nil)
    begin
        sms_id = Sms.log(number, text, t_id)
        begin
            envy = Rails.env
            prop = @PROPS_ENV['environment']['notification.sms']
            if envy == 'production' || prop
                Sms.update_status(sms_id, Sms::PROCESSING)
                Integrator.send_sms(number, text)
                Sms.update_status(sms_id, Sms::SENT)
            else
                Sms.update_status(sms_id, Sms::PROCESSED)
            end
        rescue => er1
            Sms.update_status(sms_id, Sms::ERROR)
        end
    rescue => err
        puts "#{mm} ---> General ERROR!! => #{err.inspect}"
    end
end
```

Sms class is defined as follows:

```
class Sms < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :phone_number, :content, :status
    
    NEW        = "new"
    PROCESSING = "processing"
    SENT       = "sent"
    PROCESSED  = "processed"
    ERROR      = "error"
    SMS_STATUS = [NEW, ENQUEUED, SENT, ERROR, PROCESSING]

    validates :status, inclusion: { in: SMS_STATUS }

    def self.log(number, text, t_id, status=NEW)
        sms = Sms.new(phone_number: number, content: text, status: status)
        sms.t_id = t_id
        sms.save!
        return sms.id
    end
    
    def self.update_status(sms_id, status)
        sms = Sms.find(sms_id)
        sms.status = status
        sms.save!
    end
end
```

The problem rises in the line [ Sms.update_status(sms_id, Sms::PROCESSING) ], throwing the error **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find  with id=XX**, where XX is the ID of the newly created register in the method Sms.log. If I look for the object from Rails Console, using the same ID, I'm able to find it.

Am I missing a commit? Or perhaps, the PostgreSQL 11 DB haven't yet executed the commit when Rails is executing the Sms.update_status method?

This behavior is not always happening, but happens, several times (~20% of the executions, but it varies a lot).

Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: you appear to be using a very old Ruby and Rails, and a very new PostgreSQL ... is there any option to look at upgrading the Rails and Ruby to something more modern? if not, is there a chance that you have an auto-increment turned on on the table?

Comment: So you have only one DB or a leader/follower setup? Btw why do you to re-load the record on the update? Instead of returning the record's id after creation, you could just return the instance itself. Which had the benefit that it would be faster too.

Comment: spickermann, you got it.. Thanks a lot, that was the problem.. We have a balanced DB layer, so the problem was solved by returning the object itself, just as you indicated.. Add that as the answer, please..